UseSerilog with WebHost in .NET 8
I have my host initialized as below for a .NET 8 ASP.NET Core service
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) .UseStartup<Startup>();
I am not able to find a suitable extension method for Serilog. Is there a way to use the UseSerilog extension method with Webhost?
I have checked the online documentation and nothing was found with WebHost

You should be able to use
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var logger = CreateYourLogger();

builder.Host.UseSerilog(logger);

return builder.UseStartup<Startup>();


But does IWebHostBuilder has a Host property? That is where I am stuck.

We use WebApplication.CreateBuilder(...) which does have the .Host Property.
See here for a comparision between WebHost, Host and WebApplication as different base classes to create your application: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-2-comparing-webapplicationbuilder-to-the-generic-host/

That's exactly what I've been using too, WebApplication.CreateBuilder(). Was just wondering about WebHost. Was migrating some old stuff and encountered this issue. Looks like it needs to be moved to WebApplication. Thank you for the suggestion.
